# Commerce - how to display order address in email to customer?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm new to commerce but almost I've cracked all I need to my project but one piece still left.
I can't display order shipping address. I've tried 
**{{ order.shippingAddressId(shippingAddress) }}**
but it giving me order referance number.

*From documentation:
shippingAddressId #
The id of the linked shipping address. You can get the shipping address model with the shippingAddress attribute.
shippingAddress #
This returns the address model from the database for the current shippingAddressId OR the caches address if the order is complete.*

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `order.shippingAddress` is all you need!

```
{% set orderAddress = order.shippingAddress %}

{{ orderAddress.firstName }}
{{ orderAddress.lastName }}
{{ orderAddress.address1 }}
{# ...etc! #}
```

Comment: Awesome!!  I will try it tonight. Thank you!